# Get string[] or process id's from process[] using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, string

I have opened five notepad.exe's. Now I want to know all the process id's associated with each notepad.exe.

I know I can retrieve list of notepad processes by:

Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");

But now I want string[] of process Id's of those notepad instances using LINQ. How do I do that?  I know i can create string[] and using foreach loop populate the string[] but I would like to know using LINQ.

Comment: Stringly typed data is an evil.

Comment: @Snowbear: while I generally agree (I upvoted your comment), I don't see much wrong having PIDs as strings (despite the fact they're given to you as ints already, and memory consumption). Even though they're represented with digits, they're not usable for any kind of numeric computation. They're identifiers, and strings can fit that role well.

Comment: @Martinho, Process.GetProcessById(int id)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76fkb36k.aspx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
string[] ids = processes.Select(p => p.Id.ToString()).ToArray();
```

However, I question the need to put this into a `string[]` type.  It might be better to just leave the [Process.Id](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.id.aspx) values as integers:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
var ids = processes.Select(p => p.Id);
foreach(int processId in ids)
{
   // Do something with each processId
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can write

```
var ids = Array.ConvertAll(Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad"), p => p.Id);
```

This will be (slightly) faster than `Select` and `ToArray`, since it won't need to resize the array.

If you can use an `IEnumerable<int>` instead of an array, `Select` (without `ToArray`) will be faster.

Comment: hah +1 I knew you would post this when I made my edit to do the same - I even thought SLaks would do it this way ;-)

Comment: I don't understand the 'resize the array' bit. I thought chaining `Select` and `ToArray` calls wouldn't involve any resizing because `Select` uses deferred execution and array size is calculated just before it is created. Am I wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: @gaearon: `ToArray()` has no way of knowing how big the array should be.  (`Select` cannot pass on the original size)  The resizes happen inside of `ToArray()`.

Comment: I just checked in the Reflector and you're correct. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 4):

You could do a one-liner using array conversion instead of LINQ:

```
int[] processIds = Array.ConvertAll(Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad"), 
                                    p => p.Id);
```

To get a list of process ids:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
var processIdList = processes.Select(p => p.Id).ToList();
```

To get an array instead of a list you can do:

```
var processIdList = processes.Select(p => p.Id).ToArray();
```

Note that the process Id is of type `int`. If you wanted a list of strings instead you could just do this:

```
var processIdList = processes.Select(p => p.Id.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: Or if you want a `string[]` call `ToArray()` instead of `ToList()`. If all you want to do is loop through the id's one time, you needn't call either method, because `Select()` returns an IEnumerable.

Comment: @Joel: correct, I added the `ToArray()` - this seems to reflect most closely what the OP asked for

Answer (score 1):

```
var ids = Process
    .GetProcessesByName("notepad")
    .Select(process => process.Id)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Most answers concentrate on creating `string []` out of `Process []`.
But why do you need an array at all?

If all you need to do is to loop through all items later, you don't really need to allocate memory for another array. Instead, use `IEnumerable<T>` returned by `Select`.

```
var ids = Process
    .GetProcessesByName("notepad")
    .Select(process => process.Id); // returns IEnumerable<int>

foreach (var id in ids)
    DoSomethingWith (id);
```

You can select string representations the same way, or you could project `ids` as well:

```
var stringIds = ids.Select (id => id.ToString ()); // returns IEnumerable<string>
```

Comment: (this is what I meant by the last line in my answer)

Comment: Sorry for duplication, I didn't notice you mentioned it. Should I delete the answer if it intersects with a different one?