# Cut String on first blank (space) with C#

Tags: c#, string, listbox, text-files

I'm very new to programming and i can't find a proper solution in C# for this:

I would like to cut a string (from PsList) to show it in a Listbox

I am running a CMD command and export it to a textfile - followed by the textfile being imported to a ListBox.

Currently my Listbox looks like this:

http://img856.imageshack.us/img856/700/pnr1.jpg

The problem is, that I just need the Name (or even better the PID(second collumn)) to kill the task with PsKill so I'd need to cut the String either at the first number until the next space, or if this isn't possible just the first part up to the first blank.

Also I'm not able to put the Textfile in a columned Listbox (due to missing seperators in the textfile, it's just a bunch of blanks seperating the columns) so I can't just access the correct column. Maybe it would be the easiest to put the textfile in a proper columned listbox but i'd need a hint there...

Thank you very much for any help!

Code for PsKillMethod currently is:

```
      commandBuild("pslist", parameter: "> " + System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "pList.txt"); 
        string[] pslistArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "pList.txt");
        ListBoxOutput pslistOutput = new ListBoxOutput(pslistArray);
        pslistOutput.setLabel("Select the task to kill");
        pslistOutput.setBtnVisible(true);
        pslistOutput.Show();
```

Comment: So you need to extract the ProcessName?

Comment: Can't you use `Process.GetProcessesByName("processName");` instead? Looke here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924988/get-string-or-process-ids-from-process-using-linq

Comment: Try the String.Split() method. If you're string is in `str`, call something like `str.Split(' ')`.

Comment: Please don't use a list box for this - try a `DataGridView`...

Comment: Uhm...tried LISTBOX.SelectedItem.ToString().Split(' ').Where(x => x != string.Empty).ToArray()[1] ?

Comment: Yes I'd need to extract the Processname, or better would be the PID (The first Numbers here)

Comment: Would it be possible to do a str.Split(' ') eventhough there are multiple blanks and not only one?

Comment: Another problem I'm facing right now is, that with split i get another String array - and I'll have to take everytime the second entry and put it in a new array and so on  -   Is there really no way to just cut of let's say everything up to the first number and then cut of the rest (first space after number)? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried String.Split that was mentioned in the comments?

```
var psRowElements = pslistArray[i].Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```